# React Native cannot access the component props

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am still trying to finish my first React Native app. There is another thing for which I cannot find a solution.

My application has different Screens (HomeScreen, NewsScreen, etc). Each of these screens uses the component Screen:

```
const Screen = ({props, children}) => {
    console.log("Screen props: " + props);
    return (
        <>
        <OfflineNotice />
        <Header {...props} />
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.screen}>
            <View style={styles.container}>{ children }</View>
        </SafeAreaView>
        </>
    );
}
export default Screen;
```

Each Screen component has another Header component (there is a dropdown, by choosing another option it will change the displayed information on the screen)

Here is the Header component:

```
export default function Header (props) {
    console.log("Header props: " + props.loadPredictions);
    const {sport, setSport} = useContext(AppContext);
    const logo = config[sport].logo;
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.link}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => props.navigate("Settings")}
                >
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="tune" size={32} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.logo}>
                <Image source={logo} style={styles.image} />
                <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                    <Menu
                    ref={this.setMenuRef}
                    button={<MaterialCommunityIcons name="chevron-down" size={24} onPress={this.showMenu} />}
                    >
                    <MenuItem onPress={() => {changeSport('soccer', setSport, props)}}>{i18n.t('predictions.p_1')}</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onPress={() => {changeSport('basketball', setSport, props)}}>{i18n.t('predictions.p_3')}</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onPress={() => {changeSport('volleyball', setSport, props)}}>{i18n.t('predictions.p_4')}</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onPress={() => {changeSport('hockey', setSport, props)}}>{i18n.t('predictions.p_5')}</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onPress={() => {changeSport('tennis', setSport, props)}}>{i18n.t('predictions.p_6')}</MenuItem>
                    </Menu>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};
```

And here is my HomeScreen:

```
export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  ...

  useEffect( () => {
    loadPredictions(params);
  }, []);

  const loadPredictions = async (params) => {
    ...
  }

  return (
    <Screen navi={navigation} loadPredictions={loadPredictions}>
      <View style={styles.activity}>
        <ActivityIndicator animating={loading} size="large" />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.main}>
        ...
      </View>
    </Screen>
  );
}
```

On the HomeScreen I am passing through the Screen component two props: navi and loadPredictions. Unfortunately, I cannot access them. I am getting the error undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
const Screen = ({props, children})
```

to

```
const Screen = (props)
```

and access children `props.children`

Comment: you are a magician :) Thank you. But what is the explanation about that?

Answer (score 1):

Simply because you  made a distructuring the props in Screen Component, thus if you console log the props you will find it undefined, the best approach that you do this:

```
const Screen = ({children, ...restProps}) => {
    console.log("Screen props: " + restProps);
    return (
        <>
        <OfflineNotice />
        <Header {...restProps} />
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.screen}>
            <View style={styles.container}>{ children }</View>
        </SafeAreaView>
        </>
    );
}
export default Screen;
```

In this way we will be able to access to children prop and you pass the rest of the Screen Props to what Component you want.
I hope this answer can help you out.